# Non standard vector addition

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

If addition was defined as $(a_1, a_2) + (b_1, b_2) = (a_1 + b_1, 0)$ over a a set $V$, the set of all ordered pairs of real numbers, does that special addition only apply to ordered pairs and vectors or would it also apply to scalars?
If it would apply to scalars, please explain. I have trouble visualizing how that would apply to scalars. Thanks!

Comment: Scalars are represented: $x$ $\rightarrow (x,0)$. Then $x_1+x_2=(x_1,0)+(x_2,0)=(x_1+x_2,0)$

Comment: what do you means for *scalars*? If you are thinking to the *scalars of a vector space* these are elements of a field, where the sum operation is defined in the field not in the vector space.

Comment: Hi @zoli, wouldn't it also be ok to represent scalars as: $x \rightarrow (0,x)$? then $(0,x1) + (0,x2) = (0,0)$ always?

Comment: I've never heard of representing scalars as vectors, it seems like a bad idea in general, as vectors have no requirements that they can be multiplied, unlike the requirements for scalars.

Comment: I just don't get why that would be OK.

Comment: @shoestringfries: Welcome to MSE! A vector space $(V, +, \cdot)$ consists of a non-empty set $V$ of _vectors_, a binary operator on $V$ called _vector addition_, and a _scalar multiplication_ mapping $F \times V \to V$ (with $F$ the "field of scalars"). You've specified what "$+$" means, but it's not clear what you mean by "[does $+$] 'also apply to scalars?'" Are you asking: "If $c \cdot (a_{1}, a_{2}) = (ca_{1}, ca_{2})$, is $(V, +, \cdot)$ a vector space?" If not, could you please try to clarify your question, and explain what "apply to scalars" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're writing vectors in $V$ as $(a_1, a_2)$ with $(a_1, a_2) \dot{+}(b_1, b_2) \overset{\text{def}}{=} (a_1 + b_2, 0)$, then your vector space $(V, \dot{+})$ over the field $\mathbb{F}$ is isomorphic to the subspace of $\mathbb{F}^2$ spanned by $(1, 0)$, hence isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{F}$ itself.

So, it would be perfectly reasonable to define the scalar product $c(a_1, a_2) = (ca_1, ca_2)$ for scalars $c \in \mathbb{F}$.

On the other hand, given $c\in \mathbb{F}$ and $(a_1, a_2) \in V$, suppose you use the piecewise definition $\star: \mathbb{F} \times V \to V$ for scalar multiplication, where

$$c\star (a_1, a_2) = \begin{cases}
(ca_1, 0), & c \neq 1\\
(ca_1, ca_2), & c = 1.
\end{cases}$$

(Remember, we require that $1 \star v = v$, for the multiplicative identity $1 \in \mathbb{F}$).

Since we must also have $(c_1c_2) \star v = c_1 \star (c_2 \star v)$ for scalars $c_1, c_2$, then using the above piecewise scalar product, we have

\begin{align*}(a_1, a_2) = 1 \star (a_1, a_2) &= (cc^{-1})\star (a_1, a_2) 
\\&= c\star(c^{-1} \star (a_1, a_1)) \\
&= c \star(c^{-1}a_1, 0) \\
&= (cc^{-1}a_1, 0) \\
&=(a_1, 0),\end{align*} which is not true for all $(a_1, a_2) \in \mathbb{F}.$

You can perhaps come up with some kind of non-standard scalar product, but if that piecewise definition is the one you were thinking of, it won't work.